# count only null values in SqlserverCe3.5

Tags: sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm working on asp.net website.
I'm not able to count the only null values for particular id from the database Sqlserverce.
suppose I have table called Alarm

```
alarmid     date
1   12/12/2010  
2   Null
3   4/4/2010
5   12/05/2011
6   Null
```

Here I need to find count of null values. ie 2.
I used ISNULL with COUNT function but its not working.
How to find the null values count. 
I tried like select count(date) where date is null. but not working.
pls help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(Null)` isn't supposed to count anything, but you can give the count function something else.  For example, `1`

```
select 
count(1) 
where date is null.
```

Comment: Ah much more elegant than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can do this hopefully it would work in CE

SELECT count(isnull([date],0)) as total

Update: This works in CE, above only works in SQL Server as isnull not supported in CE

select count(COALESCE(name ,1)) from test
where name is null

Comment: thanks justin but it giving total count but I want only null values count.